# AVURLAsset can't get mp3 duration in documents directory, but it works well with mp3 in app bundle

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have two mp3 files. One is in app bundle, the other is in user's Documents directory. I want to get the duration of mp3 file.

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newPath] options:nil];
[audioAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"duration"] completionHandler:^{
    CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
    float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);

    NSLog(@"duration:%f",audioDurationSeconds);
}];
```

Those codes work well with the  mp3 file in app bundle, but it doesn't work with the mp3 in Documents directory which only log "duration:0.000000". Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a way to compose a path associated to the mp3 file in document directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Professor_and_the_Plant.mp3"];

NSURL *mp3_url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
```

Comment: I know how to get path to document directory. The problem is that AVURLAsset not work with mp3 in document directory.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. My problem is using [NSURL URLWithString:]，so I get the wrong URL.

Comment: You are welcome, I have made the same mistake myself.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLAsset defaults to working quickly.  If the length or metadata isn't readily available (i.e., in the ID3 header), it doesn't yield it.  To demand the correct data, even if it takes longer, you have to give it options:

```
    static NSDictionary *options;
    if (!options) {
        NSNumber *val = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool: YES];
        options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:val, AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey, nil];
    }
    AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:options];
```

(I stuck the options in a static so I don't have to keep recreating and disposing it.)

If your assets in documents vs. app bundle are tagged differently, this could be your problem.